# How to write some Global variables to vim file in VIM

Tags: vim

I need to write some settings and variables into some text file for later retrieval.  Retrieving the file can be a simple source command.  So what is the simplest way write the file from a vimscript?

I only want to store some global variables.  Global because they will be used by multiple buffers.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what it is you want to store and restore?

Comment: One way to work with some variables is to use `:help string()` and `:help writefile()` to write the vars into a file, and use `:help readfile()` and `:help eval()` to read and turn them back into variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can save all settings to a file via this command:

```
:mkv settings.vim
```

Type `:let g:` command to list all global variables.

You can redirect the output to a file:

```
:redir > var.txt
:let g:
:redir END
```

Comment: Almost what I wanted.  but it will write too much variables.  Is there a way to write JUST some globals?

Answer (score 3):

When you `:set viminfo+=!`, global variables that start with an uppercase letter and don't contain lowercase letters are automatically persisted across Vim sessions (in the `.viminfo` file).

This is the simplest persistence mechanism available, and is used by many plugins.

Answer (score 1):

As [kev says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11540654/78845), you can use:

[`:mkview [file]`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#:mkview), which can be restored using [`:loadview`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#:loadview)

There is also:

[`:mksession`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#:mksession), whereby you can restart Vim:

```
vim -S Session.vim
```

...and your session is magically* restored.

*Not *actually* magic. Sorry.